# strncmp() function vs !(strncmp()) function

Tags: c, arduino, strncmp

I'm programming a lock where to unlock it you have to insert a PIN code in a Keypad.
I have the following variables:

```
char password_init[4] = {'1', '2', '3', '4'}; //initial password
char password[4];
```

When the user press a key in the keypad, that digit will be stored in the variable `password` and after the user press 4 digits both variables will be compared in order to give, or not, acess to the lock.

I found that one solution to do this would be using strncmp() function as:

```
if (!(strncmp(password, password_init, 4))){
Serial.println("PIN Code correct");
}
```

This works but I don't understand why I should use `!(strncmo())` instead of `strncmo()`.
If I use `if (strncmp(password, password_init, 4))` the outcome will be an incorrect PIN code.

The `strncmp()` function compares two strings, character by character, so can someone explain me why I have to use it in a negative way in orther to the initial password and the passaword pressed by the user in the keypad match?

Comment: Some people write `if (strncmp(...) == 0)`.  There are many function that return `0` on success, so eyes get used to seeing `== 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);` not only compares for **equality**, it also check for **order**.  So it needs at least **3** different return values.

> The `strncmp` function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the possibly null-terminated array pointed to by `s1` is greater than, equal to, or less than the possibly null-terminated array pointed to by `s2`. C17dr § 7.24.4.4 3

- Return some positive `int`: `s1` is "greater than" `s2`
- Return some negative `int`: `s1` is "less than" `s2`
- Return 0: `s1` is "equal to" `s2`

`!(strncmp(password, password_init, 4))` implies they are equal (up to the first 4 characters of the strings).

---

I find the below easier to read as a test for string equality.

```
if (strncmp(password, password_init, 4) == 0) {
```

Answer (score 5):

[`strncmp()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp) function returns zero when the two strings are same and non-zero when they are different.

Using `!` (logical not) operator, the result will be true (1) when the strings are same and false (0) when they are different.